# Regex to strip all leading zeroes except one

Tags: regex, scala

I am trying to strip all leading zeroes but retain one from strings .
for eg:

> if string is 000111 return 0111
>   if string is 00111 return 0111
>   if string is 0111 return 0111
>   if string is 1111 return 1111

the regex is working good, but if my string is say "3001" then the regex is returning 301 instead of 3001.

```
scala> "00111".replaceAll("[0]*(0\\d+)", "$1")
res9: String = 0111

scala> "0111".replaceAll("[0]*(0\\d+)", "$1")
res10: String = 0111

scala> "3001".replaceAll("[0]*(0\\d+)", "$1")
res11: String = 301
```

What am I missing here???

Comment: The proposed duplicate uses the same Java regex engine, and it contains multiple answers with the `^`-anchor, so it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You could do this without using a capturing group by matching 1+ times a zero from the start of the string `^0+` and replace with `0`.

If it must be followed by a digit you could use `^0+(?=\d)`

```
"00111".replaceAll("^0+", "0") // 0111
"0111".replaceAll("^0+", "0") // 0111
"3001".replaceAll("^0+", "0") // 3001
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the start-of-line anchor `^`. And `[0]` is same as `0`:

```
"00111".replaceAll("^0*(0\\d+)", "$1")
> 0111
"3001".replaceAll("^0*(0\\d+)", "$1")
> 3001
```